# How to create a css file in eclipse with e(fx)clipse plug in

Tags: css, eclipse, javafx, javafx-8, efxclipse

I have been developing a JavaFX application and when going to skin and style my application I can find how to create a css file. I have e(fx)clipse downloaded and eclipse and e(fx)clipse are both the newest versions. I have searched google and cant find anything. To create a JavaFX project file you simply go to File > New > other > and navigate to JavaFX Project. With this project it creates a css file in the package it creates. But there is no option to create a stand alone css file. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the css you will use in javaFX in an ordinary .css file so:

1)Right click on src folder

2)New->File->(Give it a name).css->Finish

**But:**
That is the way to create a css file in Eclipse.For some reason eclipse shows some warnings into css even if e(fx)clipse is installed.

Comment: That's interesting. Ill try that. My work around was to make a new JavaFX project. A new JavaFX project comes with a .css file built into it. (which i deleted at the start of development on my application). So I just took the css file out of there and put it in my project. I wonder why there isn't and option to create on like in the same area where you make a new fxml file. I guess they assume you only need one css file? So before i got your response I downloaded web dev plugins and that gave me the option i was looking for. will a css file i make from the web dev plugin also work the same?

Comment: JavaFX needs an ordinary css file but with javafx syntax (all starting with (-fx-)) take a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! I feel really dumb now. =P